# How to pass or condition in Web Service Endpoints - Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I Have a requirement to pull the orders based on the Order Type conditions.I'm able to get the data  by passing one order type,but i need to get the orders of  two order types,couldn't find Or condition to Implement.

Here the code.

```
private static SalesOrder SOStokItem(DateTimeSearch whereCondition, StringSearch Condition, int rowCount)
    {
        SalesOrder item = new SalesOrder()
        {
            RowNumber = new LongSearch { Condition = LongCondition.IsLessThan, Value = rowCount },
            ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,
            OrderType = new StringReturn(),
            OrderNbr = new StringReturn(),
        };
        if (whereCondition != null)
            item.LastModified = whereCondition;
         if (Condition != null)
        {
             //item.OrderType = new StringSearch() { Condition = StringCondition.or, Value = "RC" };
            //item.OrderType = new StringSearch() { Value = "RW" };
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP API doesn't include `or` filter conditions on string fields.
You need to issue two SOAP requests to filter the sales orders with an `or` condition.